# Reading "People Tags" inserted by Windows Live Photo Gallery

Tags: c#, image, metadata, xmp

Photo Gallery gives you the ability to mark a person's face and apply a tag to it.  I understand it inserts tags directly into the file rather than store it off in a database or accompanying metafile anywhere.

So if that's true, what data is it inserting and how is it formatted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code I wanted.  It's in C#.

```
        public void ReadWLPGRegions(string sourceFile)
    {
        string microsoftRegions = @"/xmp/RegionInfo/Regions";
        string microsoftPersonDisplayName = @"/PersonDisplayName";
        string microsoftRectangle = @"/Rectangle";
        BitmapCreateOptions createOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat | BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;

        using (Stream sourceStream = File.Open(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            BitmapDecoder sourceDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(sourceStream, createOptions, BitmapCacheOption.None);

            // Check source has valid frames
            if (sourceDecoder.Frames[0] != null && sourceDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata != null)
            {
                BitmapMetadata sourceMetadata = sourceDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata as BitmapMetadata;

                // Check there is a RegionInfo
                if (sourceMetadata.ContainsQuery(microsoftRegions))
                {
                    BitmapMetadata regionsMetadata = sourceMetadata.GetQuery(microsoftRegions) as BitmapMetadata;

                    // Loop through each Region
                    foreach (string regionQuery in regionsMetadata)
                    {
                        string regionFullQuery = microsoftRegions + regionQuery;

                        // Query for all the data for this region
                        BitmapMetadata regionMetadata = sourceMetadata.GetQuery(regionFullQuery) as BitmapMetadata;

                        if (regionMetadata != null)
                        {
                            if (regionMetadata.ContainsQuery(microsoftPersonDisplayName) &&
                                regionMetadata.ContainsQuery(microsoftRectangle))
                            {
                                Console.Writeline( regionMetadata.GetQuery(microsoftRectangle).ToString()));
                                 Console.WriteLine(regionMetadata.GetQuery(microsoftPersonDisplayName).ToString()));
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you come across a similar solution in Python?

Comment: Nope. The code relies pretty heavily on Microsoft structures, and I'm not aware of any Python library with the equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

When possible, Windows Live Photo Gallery uses [XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) to write metadata to picture files.  See [Metadata and the Windows Vista Photo Gallery](http://blogs.msdn.com/pix/archive/2006/08/16/702780.aspx) for details.

Comment: At what byte offset does the XMP start?

Comment: In the Wikipedia article I linked above, it lists "Location in file types."  For example, a JPEG has XMP data in "Application segment 1 (0xFFE1) with segment header 'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/\x00'".