# C#: Library for editing photo tags, et cetera, compatible with Live Photo Gallery

Tags: c#, image, metadata

Are there any good .net libraries I can use to read and write tags, people tags, date take, et cetera that are compatible with Windows Live Photo Gallery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FotoFly available on CodePlex is a C# library and it supports Windows Live Faces, GPS, Keywords, etc.. just as you are asking. See http://fotofly.codeplex.com/

Just an example using FotoFly to do what you want:

```
  JpgPhoto photo = new JpgPhoto(@"c:\temp\file.jpg");
  photo.ReadMetadata();

  photo.Metadata.RegionInfo.Regions.Clear();

  XmpRegion xmp = new XmpRegion();
  xmp.PersonDisplayName = "esac";
  xmp.RectangleString = "0.11, 0.25, 0.37, 0.49";

  photo.Metadata.RegionInfo.Regions.Add(xmp);
  photo.WriteMetadata();
```

It also supports Exif, Iptc, Xmp, GPS, etc..

Comment: Nice Library, they should put it on NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

WPF has BitmapMetadata which supports updating the EXIF information which I assume Windows Live Photo Gallery uses.

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475176/reading-people-tags-inserted-by-windows-live-photo-gallery) which has details about both BitmapMetadata and the metadata used by WLPG.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any library, but I was reminded of [this tool](http://www.anvo-it.de/wiki/avpicfacexmptagger:main) for converting Picasa face tags into the Windows Live Photo Gallery format.

I'm guessing the author of that tool is shelling out to run [Exif Tool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).  Maybe it could point to a possible way of getting the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try taglib#, the metadata for pictures are right now added see supported [matrix](http://gitorious.org/taglib-sharp/pages/Home).