# Face tagging information and photo metadata

Tags: metadata, photo, xmp

Is there a standard way to read/write face-tags from/into photo meta-data?

Can I use it to import face-tagging information from popular photo organizers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Metadata Working Group (i.e. Adobe, Microsoft, Sony, Nokia, and others) has developed a standard extension of XMP to do that, see Image Region Metadata Section 5.9 in the [Metadata Working Group Spec](http://www.metadataworkinggroup.com/specs/).

Another extension of XMP has been done by Microsoft for Windows Live Photo Gallery and is supported by .NET API. See [People Tagging Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719905%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Seems like Google Picasa 3.9 reads face tagging from both XMP extensions, but writes only to the one of MWG.

See more:

- [What is the standard for storing face tags and caption?](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/UQGWyIUAIjE)
- [Picasa versus Windows Live Photo Gallery | Geoff Coupe's Blog](http://gcoupe.wordpress.com/2011/12/10/picasa-versus-windows-live-photo-gallery/)
- [Picasa 3.9 bugs&questions (photo order upload, nonG+ links and account signing, sore name tags in photo](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/picasa/uJ3jYiuxSYw/KZM9k8H4LOs)
- [Reading “People Tags” inserted by Windows Live Photo Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475176/reading-people-tags-inserted-by-windows-live-photo-gallery?rq=1)