# Is there a conventional way to storing selections within the image (for example, for tagging many users on facebook?)

Tags: image, bigdata, metadata, tagging

Suppose you have hundreds of group photos, all in different formats (GIF, PNG, JPG etc). You run a social network where users may identify people on the group photos, hence on the backend, the server needs to store "rectangles" within the photo. Is there a conventional "rectangle storage" format to store such tiles within the image, as well as the software to display pictures, with these "rectangles" superimposed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three standards for regions in an image.  The Metadata Working Group standard, the Microsoft standard, and just recently, the IPTC standard.  The MWG standard was the one supported by the old Google Picasa program.  The Microsoft standard was the one supported by the old Windows Photo Gallery.  The IPTC standard is really new and I'm not sure if there is any software that supports it yet.

For the MWG standard, I would point you to their website, but it has been offline for more than a year. You can find a copy of the PDF that describes it attached to [this post](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,10183.msg53039.html#msg53039) in the Exiftool forums.  I'm not sure but I think that is the standard supported by Lightroom.

Comment: [This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12115999/3525475) has some more info on the Microsoft standard.

Comment: The IPTC standard apparently hasn't been publicly released yet.  I only found out about it because the author of ExifTool has already added support for it.

Comment: Thus far, do major platforms use avant garde EXIF standards, or do they store "rectanges" in a standard database?

Comment: The three standards I mentioned are stored as XMP structured metadata within the image.  I don't know what major platforms might be using.